# ProgressBar in Angular 8 - Bootstrapped

Tags: typescript, bootstrap-4, angular8

I'm trying to implement a progressbar using Angular 8 Bootstrapped.
The following code works fine.But when i bind the integer property the page breaks

```
<p><progress showValue="true" type="success" value={{progress}} max="100"></progress></p>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Progress Bar</h2>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{progress}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
      <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Can't bind to 'aria-valuenow' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("Basic Progress Bar
>     
>       ]aria-valuenow="{{progress}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">

Comment: is that because of double qoutes?  `("{{your_magic_value}}")`. Remove that `"___"` and use just `aria-valuenow="progress"`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Tried that.It shows the progress bar,but the value is not updated..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
attr.aria-valuenow="{{ progress }}"
```

OR

```
[attr.aria-valuenow]="{{ progress }}"
```

Comment: @techno Can you provide me a stackblitz demo where I can test?

Comment: StackBlitz demo seems difficult to recreate.Please download the solution from https://drive.google.com/file/d/11KeROn5GHSYByMzGvFWXFWiNUsojJMmv/view?usp=sharing\

Comment: Just FYI, the second one should be `[attr.aria-valuenow]="progress"`.